# How to access methods in separate classes

Tags: java, class, methods, packaging

I am trying to access a public method in a separate class but for some reason Netbeans cannot find it.  They are in the same project and packaged together.  The error message says it is looking for it in the class I am calling it from (Project6).  Any ideas on how can I get it to look in the right class (HashTable)?

```
class HashTable {

    //.....

    public HashTable(int size) {
        arraySize = size;
    }
}

public class Project6 implements ActionListener {

    //.....

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == hashButton) {
            text = hashSizeField.getText();
            HashTable(Integer.parseInt(text)); //error occurs here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a method, that's a constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method

```
public HashTable(int size)
```

is a constructor of the class HashTable, you need call with the key word **new** . The code will be:

```
class HashTable {


  public HashTable(int size) {
     arraySize = size;
  }
}

public class Project6 implements ActionListener {

//.....

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == hashButton) {
        text = hashSizeField.getText();
        new HashTable(Integer.parseInt(text)); //error occurs here
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`public HashTable` is not a method; it's a constructor for the `HashTable` class. If you want to create an instance of `HashTable`, you can do so with the `new` keyword:

```
HashTable h = new HashTable(Integer.parseInt(text));
```

---

If you're trying to call a method without an object instance, you need to declare it `static void`:

```
public static void HashTable(int size) {
    arraySize = size;
}
```

But it's best if you use another method name. `HashTable` will cause a compiler warning because it's identical to the constructor name. And by convention, method names should start with a lowercase letter.

Once you have your static method, you can call it from your other class like this:

```
HashTable.someMethod(Integer.parseInt(text));
```